# Just downloaded Android Studio, Opened my first project and I have errors in activity_main.xml without having done a single thing yet

Tags: android, kotlin

Like the title says, just downloaded Android Studio and I have errors. I am new to Android dev and Kotlin, my activity_main.xml has four errors and the preview screen does not work. Code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Hello World!"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Errors: 
Attribute android:layout_width is not allowed here 
Attribute android:layout_height is not allowed here 
Attribute tools:context is not allowed here
Element TextView is not allowed here

any help is appreciated!

Comment: Have you try to run the app?

Comment: sync gradle or give it sometime it will clear the errors,need an internet connection

Comment: Sync the project with Gradle files, or Invalidate Caches and Restart. Make sure you have good internet connectivity.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try if any of following solution works for you.

Make sure your internet connection is active

1) Just go to File->Sync Project with Gradle Files

2) Invalidate Cache/Restart -> Invalidate and Restart

3) Build-> Rebuild Project

4) Delete the .idea folder that is in the project location and then Build -> clean

Answer (score 0):

Just import your project from files,

File-> New -> Import Project -> < Select your project >

this worked for me